# JQuery visible selector and prev()

Tags: jquery, selector, visible

I am trying to determine which element with a particular class is visible. Then find its immediate previous element and slide over to it. I tried this but it is not correct.

```
if($('#sidepanel1').is(':visible')) {
         }
        else { 

        var prevpanel = $('.sidewrapper').is(':visible').prev().attr('id'); alert(prevpanel);

        $('.sidewrapper').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300); $(prevpanel).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 300);
        }

}
```

Its something to do with my use of :visible that I think is wrong. Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
var prevpanel = $('.sidewrapper').is(':visible').prev().attr('id');
```

to

```
var prevpanel = $('.sidewrapper:visible').prev().attr('id');
```

the [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns `bool`

> Unlike the other filtering methods, .is() does not create a new jQuery object. Instead, it allows you to test the contents of a jQuery object without modification.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#sidepanel1").css("visibility") == "visible")
{
 // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/is/), `is()` would only return a boolean value in that case. It doesn't return another instance of the jQuery object, so your chain is broken.